# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

this is what happened when i update buildToolsVersion from `26.0.1` to `26.0.2`.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':all:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at manifestMerger8124076249449477164.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.

but i didn't add `support-v13:26.0.1 library` to my project!!

i tried to add `tools:replace="android:value"` to manifest, and clean - rebuild, nothing changed.

`build.gradle`:

```
dependencies { 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.+' 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+' 
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+' 
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+' 
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3' 
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0' 
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar' 
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar' 
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' 
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.3.0' 
}
```

Comment: could you give us the build.gradle (app) dependencies section?

Comment: ```gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker` library uses it. You can check [the dependencies here.](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/build.gradle#L28)

Add in your `build.gradle` an explicit dependency to use the same level of support libraries:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override this conflict between the manifests of your application's dependencies by adding `tools:replace="android:value"` in the meta-data tag of your **own** manifest, and specifying the value you want to use.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
    android:value="26.0.2"
    tools:replace="android:value" />
```

P.S: If you do not already have a meta-data tag, you should add it inside your application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml